# How to reduce the image file size in python

Tags: image, python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow, python-imaging-library

I have 100 to 200 images in my directory, each image has different file size, Is there any way to assign same size to all the images?  I have tried img.resize((28,28)), it assigns same number of pixels to all images but size of images is still different.

Because When I try to flatten the images, I get following error and this error is because of different sizes of images:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-a2a6b8eb94d5> in <module>()
      1 # flattening images
      2 matrix = np.array([np.array(Image.open(path_save_image + '/' + i)).flatten()
----> 3                    for i in saved_list],'f')

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: what do you mean? are you then saving the image?

Comment: Yes I am saving the images

Comment: Same size is only achievable (ignoring some crazy theoretical stuff) **without compression** when there are different images. So i don't know what you really want to achieve, but ```.bmp``` output after resizing pixels will work.

Comment: @sascha , can you check the error above, which I am getting when I try to flatten images.

Comment: Ok, then why I am receiving this error? any idea?

Comment: Well... just double-check your newly-saved image-sizes or to be more specific: check what thos inner np.array returns in terms of shapes from everything ```os.listdir``` returns. Are there other files too?. This would be nicer if you would have split your code into preprocessing and the rest but it is not hard. **Edit:** Is every image the same in terms of number of channels?

Comment: @sascha Thanks very much, Now it is working. problem was that images had different number of channels :)

Comment: Ouch okay. Thank god it was so easy. I have to admit i was wrong earlier as the error can be an effect of uneven shapes!